# tf.Session() seemingly not closed even after exiting the with block

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am saving two graphs; one with a 2X2 zero tensor and the other with a ones tensor of the same size. I restore one of them depending on a condition.

```
import tensorflow as tf


def save_zero():
    # save a 2x2 variable filled with zeros
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        session = tf.Session()
        with tf.name_scope('dummy_graph'):
            tf.Variable([[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]], name='a', dtype=tf.float32)
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        session.run(init_op)
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.save(session, 'zero')
        session.close()


def save_one():
    # save a 2x2 variable filled with ones
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        session = tf.Session()
        with tf.name_scope('dummy_graph'):
            tf.Variable([[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]], name='a', dtype=tf.float32)
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        session.run(init_op)
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.save(session, 'one')
        session.close()


def test(boolean):
    with tf.Session() as session:
        if boolean:
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('one.meta')
            saver.restore(session, './one')

            session.run(session.graph.get_operation_by_name('init'))
            tensor = session.graph.get_tensor_by_name('dummy_graph/a:0')
        else:

            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('zero.meta')
            saver.restore(session, './zero')

            session.run(session.graph.get_operation_by_name('init'))
            tensor = session.graph.get_tensor_by_name('dummy_graph/a:0')

        return session.run(tensor)

save_zero()
save_one()
print(test(False))
print(test(True))
```

Both the calls to `test` return zeros. Observing the ops in the session suggests that the session in `test` is being reused across the two calls which AFAIK is not supposed to happen as the session is closed when `test` returns:

```
def test(boolean):
    with tf.Session() as session:
        if boolean:
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('one.meta')
            saver.restore(session, './one')
            # contains duplicate ops (suffixed with '_1')
            [print(op.name) for op in session.graph.get_operations()]
            session.run(session.graph.get_operation_by_name('init'))
            tensor = session.graph.get_tensor_by_name('dummy_graph/a:0')
        else:

            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('zero.meta')
            saver.restore(session, './zero')

            session.run(session.graph.get_operation_by_name('init'))
            tensor = session.graph.get_tensor_by_name('dummy_graph/a:0')

        return session.run(tensor)
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure if that is the issue, but you open sessions in both your saving functions without closing them. Can you add session.close() at the end of  both save_one() and save_zero() and see if you still get the problem?

Comment: @MadWombat That's not the issue. thanks anyway.

Comment: which version? I get different results from two `test` calls in 0.12

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov `pip list` tells me that it's tensorflow-gpu 0.12.1

Comment: Another suggestion is that maybe it is not the session, but rather the graph that gets reused somewhere. Can you add tf.reset_default_graph() at the very start of your test() and see if you get different results?

Comment: @MadWombat the graph is not being reused; trying to reset the default graph  gives me IndexError.

Comment: I was trying in in 12rc1 on Linux, if it's different between versions it would be a bug

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks, I will raise an issue on github

Comment: actually, I take that back, that's expected behavior because you are not resetting the graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The `tf.Session` is closed between the two calls to `test()` in your code, but you are running into a problem because the two sessions are sharing the same `tf.Graph`. Create each session with a fresh `tf.Graph` to avoid the problem.

In particular, the nodes created when you call `tf.train.import_meta_graph()` in the call to `test(False)` remain in the graph when subsequently call `tf.train.import_meta_graph()` in the call to `test(True)`. This means that each of the two calls to `session.graph.get_tensor_by_name('dummy_graph/a:0')` will return the same node (which was created when you first called `test()`).

There are a few ways to avoid this problem. The simplest is to create the `tf.Session` with its own graph:

```
def test(boolean):
    # Session will use its own graph.
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as session:
        if boolean:
            # ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot in my understanding. I was under the impression that each session instance has a default graph, turns out there is only one global default graph per process. Is that correct?

Comment: Approximately yes. There's actually a single global default graph per **thread** at any one time. Entering a `with graph.as_default():` block sets `graph` as the default graph for the current thread, and exiting the block resets it to the previous default. When you create a `tf.Session`, it uses whatever graph is the current default as its graph, unless you specify the optional `graph` argument in the initializer.

Comment: Quoting from [api docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/core_graph_data_structures#Graph.as_default), `This method should be used if you want to create multiple graphs in the same process`. Perhaps `... same **thread**` would be less confusing, can you fix that, please?

Comment: I'm not sure that that would be less confusing, even if it's more precise, because almost nobody relies on the separate default graph per thread. (It's true that you could avoid using `Graph.as_default()` if you forked a bunch of threads to create different graphs, but that's an unusual use case.) The rest of the docstring goes into more detail... but please file a GitHub issue (or make a PR) if there are other things you would change!

Comment: `The default graph is a property of the current thread`. Yep, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

To add more details to mrry answer, here's exactly what's happening:

During checkpoint saving, you are creating new graph each time, so you are saving in both checkpoints a tensor `dummy_graph/a`:

```
zero.data-00000-of-00001: dummy_graph/a - [0, 0, 
one.data-00000-of-00001: dummy_graph/a - [1, 1,
```

During first load call you first create a graph with variable `dummy_graph/a`, load `[0, 0,` into it, then call init op which will overwrite this value with `[0, 0,`

During second load call, your `import_meta_graph` will append to existing default graph. Since there's a name conflict, it will append `_1` to nodes, so now your graph will have nodes `dummy_graph/a` and `dummy_graph/a_1` and corresponding init nodes `init` and `init_1`

During second restore, your saver will restore your `[1, 1, ...` checkpoint into `dummy_graph/a`. Then you call `init` which will overwrite the value of `dummy_graph/a` with `[0, 0, ...`. You then return the value of `dummy_graph/a`

Note that after second restore, your session has two variables, and the second one is not initialized. Curiously,  `tf.report_uninitialized_variables()` does not show it, even though `sess.run('dummy_graph/a_1:0')` will throw `Attempting to use uninitialized value` error, that seems like a bug.

Comment: Why is the second one not initialized? It seems counter intuitive that duplicate (`_1`) variables are added but they are not restored with the new value, instead the old variable is overwritten leaving the new variable uninitialized

Comment: Because the second one is initialized by `init_1`, but you are calling `init`

Comment: they are not restored with new value because the saver thinks the variable is named `dummy/a`, it is not aware of the renaming to `a_1` that happened during `import_meta_graph`. IMHO it would be less confusing if there was an error instead of silent addition of `_1`, but that may be hard to implement since the `_1` addition is part lower level API